# Is there a way to route all WIFI traffic through an SSH tunnel to the internet?

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I would like to secure all wireless traffic on my local network with ssh.

Tablet/Smartphone/Computer/etc ==> WIFI Router ==> SSH TUNNEL ==> Internet

Are there routers capable of this?

Comment: It sounds like you want a VPN.

Comment: with SSH tunnelling, you have to set it up protocol by protocol, so its fine to proxy specific types of traffic (because ssh tunnels occure at OSI layer 4) but is hard to manage as the number of protocols grows. here is a article on proxying http traffic over ssh: http://ocaoimh.ie/2008/02/13/how-to-use-ssh-as-a-proxy-server/ . in this case since you want to proxy all traffic, regardless of L4 protocol, you probably want to use a L2 tunnel like VPN as David Schwartz has suggested. otherwise you have to set up tunnels for all the L4 protocols you want to proxy.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Exactly what I was about to say.